# Django Haystack can't index datetime field

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-haystack

I am using `django Haystack` with `ElasticSearch backend`. In my Model I have a `DateTimeField` which is creating problems while rebuilding_indexes.

My Model is like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    action = models.DateTimeField()
```

My Index Class is like:

```
Class MyModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    action_time = indexes.DateTimeField(null=True, model_attr="action")
```

The value i got in shell for the particular instance which is creating problem is

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
obj.action
Out[56]: datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 14, 6, 37, 430691, tzinfo=<UTC>)  # result or value of action field
```

And the error I am getting while creating indexes is

```
    if not language_code_re.search(lang_code):
        TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I tried to return strftime from indexes from prepare field , but it also doesn't work

```
    def prepare_action_time(self, obj):
        return obj.action.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') if obj.action else None
```

but it works if I return unicode representation of the datetime Value like

```
def prepare_action_time(self, obj):
        return unicode(obj.action) if obj.action else None
```

or without using `use_template=False` in my searchindex I am able to index the documents or the objects

But I am unable to get where the actual problem is. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reproduce, start a new project using Django's project template. I believe that USE_L10N = True exposes the issue, though it might be a combination of settings that causes it.

Visit the same link Ivan given, and check your settings if `USE_I10N` settings. Make it `USE_L10N = False` from `USE_L10N = True`, and your code will be working.

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24569 for more info.

```
change USE_L10N = True to  USE_L10N = False,
```

Comment: Yes, It works after changing the USE_L10N settings. Thanks

Comment: Yes, although you still have to have l10n working in a real world scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [language code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#language-code) in your settings.

If it is not set Django's `get_language` returns `None` and there's code that does not expect it.

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24569 for more info.

Comment: @rajpreetsingh can you add django version to your question?

Comment: django version is  1.8